# How I customize each color in cmap with difference interval values in heatmap seaborn subplot Python 3.6.0?

Tags: python-3.x, colors, seaborn, heatmap, subplot

I have a subplot with heatmap seaborn in Python 3.6.0

```
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [[1, 1.5, 6],
        [4, 1.6, 8],
        [0, 1.7, 10]
        ]

cmap = ["#0416FF", "#0094FF", "#00DAFF", "#006600", "#00A305"]
heat_map = sb.heatmap(data, cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

But I want customize each color in cbar with equivalent range data values like this: When data values from zero to 1 the cells will colored #0416FF and data values from 1 to 5 the cells will colored #0094FF and data values from 5 to 8 the cells will colored #00A305... That means each color in cbar will equivalent to difference interval data value. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to create the list of colors with dark blue once, light blue 4 times and green 3 times. And to set `vmin=0`, `vmax=8` to have all values clamped to that desired range.

The code below does just that. The values are added as text to easily check what's happening.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[1, 1.5, 6],
        [4, 1.6, 8],
        [0, 1.7, 10]]
colors = ["#0416FF", *(["#0094FF"]*4), *(["#00A305"]*3)]
heat_map = sns.heatmap(data, cmap=colors, vmin=0, vmax=8)
ax = plt.gca()
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data[0])):
        ax.text(j+0.5, i+0.5, data[i][j], color='gold', ha='center', va='center', fontsize=20)
```

[image: resulting plot]